# CloudWatch "UnknownEndpoint" error when running Node/express app to EC2 using Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I try to run a node/express app on ec2 using a docker image with this command "`sudo docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 name/app:latest"` and I receive the following error:

```
UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com’ at port `undefined’. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region.
  at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (/usr/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:574:46)
  at Request.callListeners (/usr/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
  at Request.emit (/usr/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
  at Request.emit (/usr/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
  at error (/usr/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:406:22)
  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:99:9)
  at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
  at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
  at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
  at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
Emitted ‘error’ event on DerivedLogger instance at:
  at DerivedLogger.transportEvent (/usr/app/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:639:12)
  at CloudWatchTransport.emit (node:events:539:35)
  at CloudWatchTransport.emit (node:domain:475:12)
  at Relay.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/winston-aws-cloudwatch/lib/index.js:15:41)
  at Relay.emit (node:events:527:28)
  at Relay.emit (node:domain:475:12)
  at Relay._onError (/usr/app/node_modules/winston-aws-cloudwatch/lib/relay.js:74:12)
  at /usr/app/node_modules/winston-aws-cloudwatch/lib/relay.js:53:57
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
 code: ‘UnknownEndpoint’,
 region: ‘us-east-1’,
 hostname: ‘logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com’,
 retryable: true,
 originalError: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: ‘NetworkingError’,
  syscall: ‘getaddrinfo’,
  hostname: ‘logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com’,
  region: ‘us-east-1’,
  retryable: true,
  time: 2022-11-17T15:06:46.985Z
 },
 time: 2022-11-17T15:06:46.985Z
}
```

**AWS AMI**: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server-20220912

"@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs": "^3.183.0",
HTTPS is enabled on server

If I clone the repo on ec2 and run it using "`pm2 --name appName start npm -- start`" it works well.

Can you help me to understand how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using the docker host network with the following flag `docker --network host` as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/).